Why are my two variables not getting set in my Update() function?
I am currently making a simulation of the human body in Unity 3D. This is in first person and with movements using transform.Translate(). But a problem I am having, is that the actualHorizontalSpeed and the vertical aren't getting set. It should every frame set its value to the one defined, but when I change it in the inspector while the game is running, I can change it like it doesn't get set. Other things in the Update() function work fine. Sorry for the messy code.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BodyHandler bodyHandler;
    private BrainHandler brainHandler;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f, moveHorizontal, moveVertical, jumpForce = 7.5f, jumpRayRange = 1.5f, runSpeed, speed, actualVerticalSpeed, actualHorizontalSpeed, speedPenalty = 0f;
    public bool isGrounded = true, jumping = false, running = false, walking = false;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called once before the first execution of Update after the MonoBehaviour is created
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        bodyHandler = GetComponent<BodyHandler>();
        brainHandler = GetComponent<BrainHandler>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        runSpeed = moveSpeed * 2f;

        
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("s") || Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            
            if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
            {
                speed = runSpeed;
                running = true;
                walking = false;

            }
            else
            {
                running = false;
                walking = true;
                speed = moveSpeed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            running = false;
            walking = false;
        }
        

        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Movement problem is caused by these \/ 2 values not even being set. You could change them in inspector while game is running and it wouldn't change back to default...
        
        
        
        if (brainHandler.conscious)
        {
            actualHorizontalSpeed = moveHorizontal * (brainHandler.consciousFunction / 100f) * (speed / 10f / (speedPenalty + 1f));
            actualVerticalSpeed = moveVertical * (brainHandler.consciousFunction / 100f) * (speed / 10f / (speedPenalty + 1f));
        }
        else
        {
            actualHorizontalSpeed = 0f;
            actualVerticalSpeed = 0f;
        }
        


        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, jumpRayRange))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.up * jumpRayRange, Color.red);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && isGrounded && speedPenalty < 1f)
        {
            jumping = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(actualHorizontalSpeed, 0f, actualVerticalSpeed);

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            transform.Translate(moveVector);
        }
        
        if (jumping)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce / (speedPenalty + 1f), ForceMode.Impulse);
            bodyHandler.fatigue += 7.5f;
            jumping = false;
        }
    }
}


I made sure all variables within the actualHorizontalSpeed and actualVerticalSpeed were not 0f, except the speedPenalty variable. I tried removing the brainHandler.consciousFunction variable which is normally 100f, and the actualHorizontalSpeed and actualVerticalSpeed were set.
I don't know if I'm just dumb, but I think that there maybe is some obstacle in using the brainHandler.conciousFunction which prevents that part of the code to get set, even though the variable is always fluctuating between 95-100f.
If any of you know any fixes, it would make me really happy if you posted about it in the comments :)

What is "brainhandler.concious" when you say not being set are the values 0? What happened when you added debug statements  to check values?

Well I viewed all values in the inspector instead of making debug statements, and as I said, the actualSpeeds don't update even though they're included in the Update() function. The brainHandler.consciousFunction is at 100f when this happens. I don't think it's because of the brainHandler.consciousFunction's number that the update doesn't happen, but I'm thinking it could either be an error, or maybe some known problem I don't know of, since I'm relatively new. The problem could be caused by the fact that I'm using the newest Unity Editor, which is still in preview (Version 6000.0.13f1).

well, the difference between looking at values in the inspector, and adding debug statements is you can do things like see what path through your code is taken, what values are what where.. not just in the blink of an eye its all over... I would doubt that the unity version matters in this one.   Problem is you havent provided a [mcve] so, we dont know whats happening, we cant recreate it, so you're gonna need to debug it

The last time I was knocked unconscious, I did not stop moving until a bit after I hit the ground! You should set a breakpoint where you're setting those values, and have a look at all the variables used in that assignment statement.

@jwdonahue I might try and do this.

@BugFinder I'll try and do that then, thanks!

I found the error in my game. A very important thing, I failed to mention, was that the BrainHandler script came from another GameObject. Then when I wrote my script, I forgot to write the GameObject first like this: brainHandler =  TheGameObject.GetComponent<BrainHandler>(); This mistake caused every piece of code associated with the brainHandler to not get run. I'm surprised that it didn't create compiler errors. Here's the code:
    private BodyHandler bodyHandler;
// Here I make a variable for the script, but no seperate GameObject like I should've.
private BrainHandler brainHandler;
public float moveSpeed = 1f, moveHorizontal, moveVertical, jumpForce = 7.5f, jumpRayRange = 1.5f, runSpeed, speed, actualVerticalSpeed, actualHorizontalSpeed, speedPenalty = 0f;
public bool isGrounded = true, jumping = false, running = false, walking = false;
private Rigidbody rb;

// Start is called once before the first execution of Update after the MonoBehaviour is created.
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    bodyHandler = GetComponent<BodyHandler>();
    // I used GetComponent<>() like it was another script on the same object.
}

You can see that I somehow fail to define the GameObject the BrainHandler script's GameObject, even though it's on a seperate object. This error was so dumb, and I apologize to anyone, who've used their precious time, trying to help me.¨
This is the corrected GetComponent:
brainHandler = brain.GetComponent<BrainHandler>();

I defined the brain as a GameObject.
Thanks for you guys' help!

It wouldn't throw a compile error because you set brainhandler to a get component. It doesnt know that will be null. If its only on another object then im surprised the brainhandler used later im more surprised there was no null reference exception.

That makes sense. Sorry I'm pretty new to programming.
